# How can I convert string to "command" in Python?

Tags: python, string

How can I convert this so it could execute?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shady\Desktop\tet.py", line 14, in <module>
    exec test
  File "<string>", line 1
    print "hello world"
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

source:

```
test = ''.join(clientIp.split("test6")[1:])
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual code you're trying to run?
BTW, it's also a bad idea to be 'exec'ing a string provided by a user without running it through some sort of validation.

Comment: There are prettymuch no reasons to use `exec`.

Comment: @Make Graham: I disagree. There are uses for exec. No uses for an inexperienced programmer, but exec is a tool to be used for the times when no other tool will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use `lstrip()` on the string to get rid of any leading whitespace before passing it to `exec`.